# Shrink image on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently building a small site and would like the logo to scale down when I scroll down my page.

Currently the way it works, the header drops in size but the logo remains the same size.

How do I fix this so it scales the image down too?

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/LhwvLgvj/

```js
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
/**
 * cbpAnimatedHeader.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
        header = document.querySelector( '.cbp-af-header' ),
        didScroll = false,
        changeHeaderOn = 1; // this is initially set to 300

    function init() {
        scrollPage();
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
            if( !didScroll ) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
            }
        }, false );
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            classie.add( header, 'cbp-af-header-shrink' );
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'cbp-af-header-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```

```css
body {
  background:skyblue
}

.cbp-af-header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: #f6f6f6;
 z-index: 10000;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
 transition: height 0.3s;
}

.cbp-af-header .cbp-af-inner {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 69em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 1.875em;
}

.cbp-af-header h1,
.cbp-af-header nav {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

 /* We just have one-lined elements, so we'll center the elements with the line-height set to the height of the header */
.cbp-af-header h1,
.cbp-af-header nav a {
 line-height: 200px;
}

.cbp-af-header h1 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #333;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 font-size: 4em;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
}

.cbp-af-header nav {
 float: right;
}

.cbp-af-header nav a {
 color: #aaa;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin: 0 0 0 20px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.cbp-af-header nav a:hover {
 color: #333;
}

/* Transitions and class for reduced height */
.cbp-af-header h1,
.cbp-af-header nav a {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink {
 height: 90px;
}

.cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink h1,
.cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink nav a {
 line-height: 90px;
}

.cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
}

/* Example Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 55em) {
 
 .cbp-af-header .cbp-af-inner {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .cbp-af-header h1,
 .cbp-af-header nav {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
 }

 .cbp-af-header h1,
 .cbp-af-header nav a {
  line-height: 115px;
 }

 .cbp-af-header nav a {
  margin: 0 10px;
 }

 .cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink h1,
 .cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink nav a {
  line-height: 45px;
 }

 .cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
 }

 .cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink nav a {
  font-size: 1em;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 32.25em) {
 .cbp-af-header nav a {
  font-size: 1em;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 24em) {
 .cbp-af-header nav a,
 .cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink nav a {
  line-height: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="cbp-af-header">
    <div class="cbp-af-inner">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200">
        </div>
</div>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>
<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>
<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>

<p>
test
</p>
```

Comment: Try adding `height:100%` to your `img` and it's parent

Comment: @DenisSheremet I have tried this here but without success: https://jsfiddle.net/LhwvLgvj/1/

Comment: Updated my comment

Comment: @DenisSheremet Ooooh nice! Can you add as an Answer & I'll green tick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `height:100%` to both your `img` and it's parent. Your code not working because `img` by default have `height` of original image file, not of it's cotainer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding a few things. First of all make the headers inner div to have the height of the header with:

```
.cbp-af-header .cbp-af-inner {
  height: 100%; /* THIS ADDED */
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 69em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.875em;
}
```

Then make the image also take the height of the header with this:

```
.cbp-af-header .cbp-af-inner img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This is the most basic example of how you can make the image scale. If you would like it to remain certain width and scale etc you'd need to do a couple of things more and there's many options which also depend on your needs.

Comment: No problem :) Glad to be helpful.